# How to open Drawer on clicking Icon inside an AppBar in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have my files as follows:

**homepage.dart**

```dart
return Scaffold{
      appBar: CustomAppBar(),
      drawer: CustomDrawer(),
}
```

**CustomAppBar.dart**

```dart
class HomePageAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
return AppBar{
      leading: InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                // Need to open drawer when clicked
              },
              child: FaIcon(
                FontAwesomeIcons.bars,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
                size: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.size,
              ),
            ),
}
@override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
}
```

**CustomDrawer.dart**

```dart
return Drawer{
}
```

Now since my AppBar and Drawer are in separate files, I cannot use Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer() to open the drawer. I tried setting a GlobalKey to my Drawer but was now able to access it from my CustomAppBar file.

I tried converting the CustomAppBar.dart file to a Scaffold so that it contains my appbar and my drawer and used Scaffold.of(context).openDrawer(). This caused the drawer to open and display only in the appbar area (Probably because of using PreferredSizeWidget).

How can I make the drawer open on clicking the AppBar's icon given that they are placed in separate files? I want to keep my AppBar and Drawer in separate files.

Answer (score 1):

Declare globalkey outside the class (Global) or create a static memeber

```
 GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _globalkey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

opend Drawer using globalkey.

```
 _globalkey.currentState?.openDrawer();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

```
onPressed: () {
          showModalBottomSheet<void>(
            context: context,
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return Container(
                height: 200,
                color: Colors.amber,
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      const Text('Modal BottomSheet'),
                      ElevatedButton(
                        child: const Text('Close BottomSheet'),
                        onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
```

Comment: This is different from a drawer that opens from the left correct? I would want the drawer to open on clicking the button as well as on dragging from the left side of the screen and I guess only drawer can achieve this?